# Authorize.Net Change Information

Tags: authorize.net

I have created the sandbox account of authorize.net and during the information filling it is not asked me for the any security question to answer.

I created the account successfully but when I go to get the transaction key then it is asking for the security question to answer that I did not enter.

I go through the entire documentation but still not able to resolve it

Your help in this matter will be highly appreciated. I need to change this security question or get rid of it.

Comment: unable to get any solution

Comment: The default security answer is "Simon"

Comment: You have asked a lot of question and have yet to accept any answers. This site goes both ways. If you expect help you should reward those who help you by accepting their answer. Read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and start giving back to the community.

Answer (score 2):

For new Authorize.Net sandbox accounts, the default security answer is "Simon"

Comment: Hi @UmairKhan. If this, or any answer, has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.